# Убрать пустые значения в массиве (array_diff)

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Есть задача. При вводе в текстовые поля списка из слов (Ключ 1, Ключ 2, Ключ 3), нужно пересечь эти слова друг с другом и вывести в отдельное текстовое поле (Результат).

Вводя список в виде строк, я перевожу их в список-массив, разбивая строку на значения массива.

Мне также нужно, чтобы перед пересечением слов у массивов не было пустых значений. Для этого использую функцию array_dif(). Но если я вбиваю ключи в текстовые поля и где-то пропуская значение, оставляя пускую строку, эта функция не срабатывает, а мне выводится пересечение нормального значения с пустым. Вместо 3-х слов - два. Вместо 2-х - одно.

Вопрос 1. Как реализовать удаление пустых значений в массиве перед их пересечением?

Вопрос 2. Как вывести эти значения в текстовое поле "Результат"?

Код ниже:

```
<?php        
function keys()
    {
        // Берём ключи из форм
        $key1 = $_POST['key1'];
        $key2 = $_POST['key2'];
        $key3 = $_POST['key3'];

        // Переводим строки в массив
        $key1_array = explode("\n", $key1);
        $key2_array = explode("\n", $key2);
        $key3_array = explode("\n", $key3);

        // Убираем пустые (нулевые) значения в массивах
        $key1_array = array_diff($key1_array, array('', null));
        $key2_array = array_diff($key2_array, array('', null));
        $key3_array = array_diff($key3_array, array('', null));

        // Пересекаем все значения ключей массивов друг с другом
        for($a = 0; $a < count($key1_array); $a++)
        {
            for($b = 0; $b < count($key2_array); $b++)
            {
                for($c = 0; $c < count($key3_array); $c++)
                {
                    $massiv = $key1_array[$a].' '.$key2_array[$b].' '.$key3_array[$c];
                    echo $massiv.'<br>';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    keys();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PPC</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        <label>
            Ключи 1: <textarea name="key1" rows="5"></textarea><br>
            Ключи 2: <textarea name="key2" rows="5"></textarea><br>
            Ключи 3: <textarea name="key3" rows="5"></textarea><br>
            Результат: <textarea id="text" name="result" rows="10"><?php keys();?></textarea><br>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Перемножить"><br>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```
$key1_array = array_diff($key1_array, array('', null));
```

поставить

```
foreach($key1_array as $key=>$value){
    if(empty($value) || in_array($value,array("\n","\r","\n\r","\r\n"))){
        unset($key1_array[$key]);
    }
    unset($key,$value);
}
```

И так для каждого из массивов

Comment: В общем, часть совета помогла. Вот так сработало: $key1_array = array_diff($key1_array, array("\n","\r","\n\r","\r\n")); для каждого массива. Но цикл с пересечением всё-равно не сработал. Перед циклом нужна пользовательская сортировка списка. Вот так: usort($key1_array, function ($a, $b) { return strcmp($a, $b);}); И тогда всё происходит как нужно. Спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю сделать вот что:

```
while(strpos($key1, "\n\n")) $key1 = str_replace("\n\n", "\n", $key1);
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, куда и вместо чего это поставить?

Answer (score 0):

Я тебе немного не понял но думаю ты имее в виду это

```
0 0 0 конец
а б в
0 0 1 конец
а б е
0 1 0 конец
а д в
0 1 1 конец
а д е
1 0 0 конец
г б в
1 0 1 конец
г б е
1 1 0 конец
г д в
1 1 1 конец
г д е
```

так

```
<?php        

        // Берём ключи из форм
        $key1 = $_POST['key1'];
        $key2 = $_POST['key2'];
        $key3 = $_POST['key3'];
        // Переводим строки в массив

        $key1_array = explode("\r\n", $key1);
        $key2_array = explode("\r\n", $key2);
        $key3_array = explode("\r\n", $key3);

        // Убираем пустые (нулевые) значения в массивах
        $key1_array = array_diff($key1_array, array('', null));
        $key2_array = array_diff($key2_array, array('', null));
        $key3_array = array_diff($key3_array, array('', null));


        // Пересекаем все значения ключей массивов друг с другом
        for($a = 0; $a < count($key1_array); $a++)
        {
            for($b = 0; $b < count($key2_array); $b++)
            {
                for($c = 0; $c < count($key3_array); $c++)
                {
                    echo $a." ".$b." ".$c." конец<br>";
                    $massiv = $key1_array[$a].' '.$key2_array[$b].' '.$key3_array[$c];
                    echo $massiv.'<br>';
                }
            }
        }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PPC</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        <label>
            Ключи 1: <textarea name="key1" rows="5"></textarea><br>
            Ключи 2: <textarea name="key2" rows="5"></textarea><br>
            Ключи 3: <textarea name="key3" rows="5"></textarea><br>
            Результат: <textarea id="text" name="result" rows="10"></textarea><br>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Перемножить"><br>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

explode("**\r\n**", $key1);